# SQL Para Contar Se for Maior Que 1

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-select

Meu problema é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho que fazer uma condição caso o SEQ_VENDA tenha mais de 001 NUMERO, ele trazer os dados do SELECT. E se tiver só 1 NUMERO referente ao SEQ_VENDA não trazer no SQL

Comment: O que você quer dizer como referente? e "caso o SEQ_VENDA tenha mais de 001 NUMERO". Poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: O número é uma sequencia certo? e o SEQ_venda é a sequencia da venda, se na venda tiver só 1 item, não é pra trazer nada, mas se na venda tiver 2 itens, o NUMERO vai ser 001 e 002 e ai sim, trazer os dados.

Answer (score 3):

retorna uma linha e quantas vezes ocorre `(SQL Para Contar Se for Maior Que 1)`

```
SELECT *,
       count(*) AS c
FROM ITENS_VENDA
GROUP BY SEQ_VENDA
HAVING c > 1
ORDER BY c DESC
```

**Se você quiser as linhas completas**

```
select * from ITENS_VENDA where SEQ_VENDA in (
    select SEQ_VENDA from ITENS_VENDA
    group by SEQ_VENDA having count(*) > 1
)
```

**Exemplo tabela**

[image: tabela]

**Resultado**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]